# dotnet restore unable to load shared library 'libproc' or one of its dependencies on Mac OS

Tags: c#, .net

I am following the tutorial for .NET on

https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/macos

I installed the .NET SDK and create an app by using on macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.5:

```
~$ dotnet new console -o myApp
```

which gives me an error of:

```
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on myApp/myApp.csproj...
Unable to load shared library 'libproc' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES 
environment variable: dlopen(liblibproc, 1): image not found
```

I tried to do

```
export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/
```

before deleting the created folder and files, and I get a lot of printed statements that look like:

```
dyld: loaded: /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.1/System.IO.Compression.Native.dylib
```

as well as the same error:

```
The template "Console Application" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on myApp/myApp.csproj...
Unable to load shared library 'libproc' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES 
environment variable: dlopen(liblibproc, 1): image not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately it cannot be reproduced. Maybe your Mac is broken by some other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by using fs-usage to examine where does dotnet try to find libproc.dylib. In my case, I found that dotnet was trying to find libproc.dylib at ~/libproc.dylib, so I copied /usr/lib/libproc.dylib to ~/libproc.dylib and dotnet worked.

I think this is not a satisfactory answer so if anyone knows why dotnet was not looking for libproc.dylib at /usr/lib/libproc.dylib, please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: I created a symlink (`$ ln -s /usr/lib/libproc.dylib libproc.dylib`) to the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that my comment only worked when I started `pwsh` in `~`.

I created a symlink in `/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/6` that points to `libproc.dylib`:

```
/usr/local/microsoft/powershell/6$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libproc.dylib libproc.dylib
```

PowerShell starts correctly in any directory.

This will likely need to be recreated when I upgrade PowerShell Core (via Homebrew Cask).

** edit **

I should have read the question more closely--it was about `dotnet`, not `pwsh`.